# Positioning a page

Tags: header, position, centering, css-position

I want to create a header similar to facebook where position:fixed. and when you zoom-out the whole page centers itself and when I zoom-in the header also streches..
When I use position:fixed and zoom-in some contents disappear due to lack of space on the window..

```
<div id="header_line" ></div>
<div id="header">
  <div id="heading_name" ><a href="home.php">Home</a> </div>

<div id="heading_name" style="left:28%;">Advertisement Board</div>
<div id="heading_name" style="left:46%;">Advertise</div>
<div id="heading_name"  style="left:60%;">Sign In</div>
<div id="heading_name"  style="left:76%;">About Us</div>



</div>

<style>


#header_line{
    position:fixed;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    width:1370px;
    height:7px;
    z-index:20;
    background-color:#F60;
}
#header{
    position:fixed;
    left: 0px;
    z-index:20;
    top: 7px;
    width:1370px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color:#003;
    border-bottom:thick;
    border-bottom-color:#000;
    box-shadow:2px 5px 5px 1px #033;

    }

</style>
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you included the code you tried so far.

Comment: @ajacian81 here it is..
I'm kind of a newbie..
So my code may be little amateur